# Magento-2 : How to access specific categories and its all products URL for specific customer after logged in

Tags: magento2, customer, catalog, access

I am working on a custom module, I implement functionality if the customer is logged in then he/she only access allowed categories and its products.

I have categories data as per specific customer. currently, the customer only accesses its categories menu but if access directly from URL, I am not able to put the restriction for it.

If he/she directly access other categories and its products using URL then he/she redirect to 404 page or can't access categories and its products URL.

Comment: I think it possible by 1) create customer attribute and assign a category to the specific customer only.  step 2) using event observer you can check it.

Comment: @NikunjVadariya I have already customer with assign category data but issue for product URL if customer directly open from URL, How to check it my customer category data in observer?

Comment: @suresh chikani, i am working on some thing like this ..like i want to show some additional products from category only to specified customer group..like b2b customer only can see some additional products ...i created attribute and planning to check condition in list page ....so help me here